# Are there commands for execute XFCE's menu entries to reboot or power off/shut down?

Tags: command-line, terminal, xfce, shutdown, reboot

There is `Herunterfahren`(DE)/`Shut Down` and `Neustarten` (DE)/`Reboot`:

[image]

Is it possible to execute these GUI entries from the command line? If so, what exactly are the commands?

I already checked [XFCE's docs page for the power manager](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/getting-started), but as far as I understood it, these commands aren't listed there.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/771187/158442

Comment: @muru Cool, thank you! If you were to post your comment as a reply, I would be happy to mark it as solved.

Comment: I'll ping the OP of that post to post it here as well, you can accept their answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://askubuntu.com/a/771187/158442:

I think what you want is xfce4-session-logout ([online manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xfce4-session-logout.1.html)).

Excerpt from the manpage (reformatted, filtered):

```
The xfce4-session-logout command allows you to programmatically logout
   from your Xfce session. It requests the session manager to display  the
   logout  confirmation  screen,  or,  if  given  one  of the command-line
   options below, causes the session manager to take the requested  action
   immediately.

OPTIONS:
   --logout     Log out without displaying the logout dialog.
   --halt       Halt without displaing the logout dialog.
   --reboot     Reboot without displaying the logout dialog.
   --suspend    Suspend without displaying the logout dialog.
   --hibernate  Hibernate without displaying the logout dialog.
   --fast       Do  a  fast shutdown.  This instructs the session manager not to
                save the session, but instead to quit everything quickly.
```

- So to shut down: `xfce4-session-logout --halt`
- To reboot: `xfce4-session-logout --reboot`

To get the dialogue where one can pick an action manually, run it without arguments:

```
xfce4-session-logout
```